# QT return shell command result non blocking

Tags: qt, qprocess

In qt im trying to run the following shell command:

```
 arp | grep -i 'test'
```

I currently have the following code:

```
QString Network::getMac(){
     QProcess sh;
     sh.start("sh");
     sh.waitForStarted();
     sh.write("arp  -n| grep -i 'test'");
     sh.closeWriteChannel();
     sh.waitForFinished();
     QString line=  sh.readAll().replace("\n","").toLower();
     return line;
}
```

I want to use the mac e.g. like:

```
  QString mac = objectOfClassThatHasTheFunction->getMac();
```

It works perfectly fine but the problem is that it takes really long and is blocking the prorgram.
The docs say `waitForFinished Blocks until the process has finished and the finished() signal has been emitted, or until msecs milliseconds have passed.` But How can I return the result without blocking?
How Should I run a QProcess without blocking when I want to use the result?

*I can speed up the process by using arp -n but I want to find out how to use qprocess correctly.*

Answer (score 2):

**bool QProcess::startDetached(qint64 *pid = nullptr)**

```
 QProcess sh;
 sh.setProgram("sh");
 sh.setArguments({"arp -n | grep -i 'test'"});
 connect(&sh,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,this,&YOUR_CLASS::YOUR_SLOT);
 sh.start(); //EDIT: startDetached() is not emitting signals
```

YOUR_CLASS::YOUR_SLOT is the slot where you can get the standard output

Take care about the scope of "sh" variable. It may be destroyed, if declared in a function.

Comment: I saw the slot signals for qprocess but how do you return it from a function call?

Comment: This way, you dont need to return it.  In your slot, just use: sh.readAllStandardOutput(). The slot will be called asynchronously, when you get some text on stdout, and just display it, or process it.

Comment: I want to return it e.g. QString mac = someClass->getMac();

Comment: You have three approaches:
1. Blocking the main thread until you get information from the executed process. You implemented it. 
2. Without blocking the main thread, as in the first G.M. example.
3. Asynchronous, as in my example. This way, you will receive what you need in the slot, connected to readyReadStandardOutput signal. This signal will be emitted anytime, when your shell command outputs something. This is the place where you will receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really *must* wait for the result then you could make use of an event loop (untested)...

```
QString Network::getMac ()
{
  QProcess sh;
  QEventLoop el;
  QObject::connect(&sh, &QProcess::started, &el, &QEventLoop::quit);
  sh.start("sh");
  el.exec();
  QObject::connect(&sh, &QProcess::finished, &el, &QEventLoop::quit);
  sh.write("arp  -n| grep -i 'test'");
  el.exec();
  QString line = sh.readAll().replace("\n","").toLower();
  return line;
}
```

Generally speaking, though, you should connect to and act upon the various [`QProcess` signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#signals).  Without error checking it could be something like...

```
void Network::getMac ()
{
  auto *sh = QProcess;
  QObject::connect(&sh, &QProcess::started,
                   [sh]()
                   {

                     /*
                      * The process has started so write the command.
                      */
                      sh->write("arp  -n| grep -i 'test'");
                   });
  QObject::connect(&sh, &QProcess::finished,
                   [sh]()
                   {

                     /*
                      * The process has finished so fetch and use the
                      * data.
                      */
                     QString line = sh->readAll().replace("\n","").toLower();
                     process(line);

                     /*
                      * The QProcess `sh' was new'd so we need to make
                      * sure it's deleted when control is returned to
                      * the event loop.
                      */
                     sh->deleteLater();
                   });
  sh->start("sh");
}
```

Comment: I want to return the resullt, if it is possible without waiting thats even better.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by `"...return the resullt, if it is possible without waiting..."`.  The command will take a finite amount of time to complete -- there's no getting round that.  Using a local `QEventLoop` allows Qt to process other events while waiting for the `QProcess` to finish.  Sorry if I've misunderstood the issue.

Comment: sorry it was in the response to' if you really must wait for the result' I thought you were suggesting it was not needed to wait.